# PHP socket_read() only gets the first byte of the stream

Tags: php, linux, sockets

I'm getting a very weird behavior when using socket_read() in linux.

I'm using socket_read with a 2048 buffer limit.

While on my windows system it gets the whole response, on my Linux server it just gets the first byte of the response.

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if (!socket_connect($sock, 'my-server.dyndns.org', 8888)) {
   die('no connect');
}

$req = 'request';
socket_write($sock, $req);

if (false !== ($buf = socket_read($sock, 2048)) {
    echo $buf; // This only contains the first byte of the response.
}

socket_close($sock);
```

If I call socket_read() again it gets the rest of the string:

```
// This works: 

while((false !== ($buf = socket_read($sock, 2048)))) {
    echo "Read ".strlen($buf)." bytes from socket_read().\n";
    if ($buf == "") break;
    $b .= $buf;
    sleep(1);
}

/* Output: 
 *
 * Read 1 bytes from socket_read().
 * Read 307 bytes from socket_read().
 * Read 0 bytes from socket_read().
 * Done.
 */
```

If I wait for 2 seconds before calling socket_read(), I also get a valid response:

```
// This also works:

sleep(2);
if (false !== ($buf = socket_read($sock, 2048)) {
    echo $buf; // all 308 bytes are read correctly.
}
```

Shouldn't socket_read() wait for the buffer to get full, or for the end of string?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your problem? Are you wondering why you need to wait a little after write until you can read something from the socket?

Comment: Problem is I can trust neither of the above solutions. I can't wait for an arbitrary amount of time and suppose that the response is valid. The other solution has a similar problem: If the output is sent in chunks I might break the read loop before all the reading is done.

Comment: Well you always need to wait for the response. You could check if there is data, and if not, try again (and again, and again). Build the buffer your own, parse and handle socket errors in the meanwhile.

Comment: @hakre I can't really be sure when the output is done.

Comment: Sure, that's why you need to wait for it. It's network, you need to check if there is something ready for reading or not.

Answer (score 2):

It's known that the network stack on linux is way better (faster) than on windows (that's subjective, let's just say: it behaves differently). On the other hand that means, that your code needs to deal with the differences, too.

Sockets are not real-time but asynchronous. So if you write something to a socket you can not expect that you already can read on it. You need to give the remote daemon some time to actually response to your write.

Only if the remote side did actually wrote something to your socket and the network has transferred that data, you can read it.

Comment: The manual suggests that socket_read will return when the buffer length specified is read or a stream termination character is read. So when I'm calling it I am assuming I am waiting for the remote deamon. Nevertheless, it appears to return instantly with whatever is currently in the buffer.

Comment: You might have more control with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php + `MSG_WAITALL` flag. Try it.

Comment: No, it is not "known that the linux network stack is 'better' or 'faster'". This is just spin. It might be, but you can't assume that it is.

Comment: @MarkR: Actually that's subjective, right. For example what is "better"? What does mean "faster"? So you're totally right that this is only the perception I (and many others I know) have. But I won't call that spin, I'm not in the need to do marketing. So just you know. And for the answer: It just means that there are differences between the OSes which create need in dealing differently according to each platform. Edited the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @hakre MarkR is technically right. It can't be assumed that a given network stack is faster than another. That said, my experience is that PHP has a good number of tools which are better suited to a LAMP environment (probably because LAMP was more or less assumed for a good period of PHP's history).

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Yeah, I already edited the question because it's subjective. But whenever I develop cross-platform code, I can more specifically deal with what's going on on *nix compared to win in networking. It might not be correct to say it's "faster", and most often it can be dealt with both platforms, it's just like it is :). Something similar is with threads. However for this answer, the most important part is that you can not expect both network stacks to behave the same. And if you're coding, you don't need to know what's better or not, but to get the code working on both OS'es.

Comment: @hakre Oh, I completely agree, given a reasonable install of Linux vs. Windows on a comparable hardware architecture, my experience is that *nix is faster, easier, and more reliable. But, since comparable architecture/reasonable *nix install are not reliable assumptions...

Answer (score 2):

You need to quantify "the whole response".

If by "the whole response", you mean, all the data that is written to the socket before it is closed, then you need to use a loop getting more data. recv is not guaranteed to send all the data in a single chunk.

I would strongly recommend that you don't use the ancient socket_ functions, but instead the fsockopen and fread instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the manual of php says that the read ends with a \r \n if the type is set to PHP_NORMAL_READ 
string socket_read ( resource $socket , int $length [, int $type = PHP_BINARY_READ ] )

Maybe in your case must be socket_read($sock, 2048,PHP_NORMAL_READ) to indicate that it must stop reading at a \r\n

Otherwise you can try with a normal fsockopen, and fread instead... it usually goes fine on linux.

Comment: This is a custom server answering and it is working in binary mode (ends with \0). So this in not a solution in my case.