# Telnet to localhost works but not IP in php socket code

Tags: php, sockets, networking, telnet

Here is my php socket reading code

```
<?php
$host = "0.0.0.0";
$port = 5060;

set_time_limit(0);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");

$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

while(1) {
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");

    while ($input = socket_read($spawn, 1024)) {

        $input = trim($input);
        echo "Client Message : " . $input;
    }

    socket_close($spawn);
}
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I'm able to do `telnet localhost 5060` but i'm not able to do `telnet 192.168.12.154 5060`.It exists after 1 input only.
Can any say what might be wrong

Comment: what hapens when you bind directly to `192.168.12.154`?

Comment: I'm not really sure what do you want to do and how are you doing it, but let's give it a try...is the host 192.168.12.154 reachable/pingable? Are you connecting with "the" telnet program or with your script?

Comment: @Eun, It shouldn't matter.  `0.0.0.0` means to bind to any address.

Comment: @Brad, I know but lets see if it works there or the network is not correctly assigned / configured etc...

Comment: @iBlue, Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: @all its my local system.When i bind directly to IP and try to do a telnet it simply jumps back to the terminal

Comment: Script works for me on both addresses, maybe you have allready binded on `192.168.12.154:5060`? Check `netstat`. Also set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see possible problems.

Comment: no i haven't ......and i'm unable to do telnet to 192.168.12.154:5060,i first connect but the moment i enter a letter it exits from telnet

Comment: Maybe something in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712256/php-socket-read-only-gets-the-first-byte-of-the-stream